# Typescript: Array of a generic with different args

Tags: typescript

Consider a function that's called like:

```
func([
   {object: object1, key: someKeyOfObject1},
   {object: object2, key: someKeyOfObject2}
])
```

It's got an array. I want to enforce that the `key` field holds a key of the object that is held in `object`. **Every object can have a different shape.**

Constructing such a type for a single object is easy:

```
type Type<T> = { obj: T, key: keyof T }
```

However, I don't know how to create an array out of it, where every single element would be enforced. `Type<any>[]` would all drop types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restricting this on the function side is difficult. I don't even think there's a generic way to do that.

**Non-generic solution: function overload**

```
interface Item<TObject> {
  object: TObject
  key: keyof TObject
}

function func<T1, T2, T3, T4>(items: [Item<T1>, Item<T2>, Item<T3>, Item<T4>]): void
function func<T1, T2, T3>(items: [Item<T1>, Item<T2>, Item<T3>]): void
function func<T1, T2>(items: [Item<T1>, Item<T2>]): void
function func<T1>(items: Item<T1>[]): void {

}

func([
  { object: { a: '1' }, key: 'a' },
  { object: { b: '1' }, key: 'b' },
  { object: { c: '1' }, key: 'a' }, // not allowed
])
```

**Solution 2: enforcing types on the calling side**
Basically, you rely on utility function. There's still way to make an error here and have compiler miss it (see last item in the example)

```
interface Item<TObject extends object> {
  object: TObject
  key: keyof TObject
}

function func(items: Item<any>[]) {

}

function createItem<T extends object>(object: T, key: keyof T): Item<T> {
  return {
    object,
    key
  }
}

func([
  createItem({ a: 1 }, 'a'),
  createItem({ b: 2 }, 'f'), // not allowed
  { object: { b: 2 }, key: 'f' }, // allowed
])
```

**Solution 3: create a processor object with generic add method**

```
interface Item<TObject> {
  object: TObject
  key: keyof TObject
}

function createMyArrayProcessor() {
  const array: Item<any>[] = []

  return {
    add<T>(item: Item<T>) {
      array.push(item)

      return this
    },
    result() {
      // process the array here and return the result
    }
  }
}

const result = createMyArrayProcessor()
  .add({ object: { a: '1' }, key: 'a' })
  .add({ object: { b: '1' }, key: 'b' })
  .add({ object: { c: '1' }, key: 'a' }) // not allowed
  .result()
```

Answer (score 1):

It is doable without extra functions but with small type overhead:

```js
type Entity<Obj, Key> = {
    object: Obj,
    key: Key
}

type IsValid<T extends Entity<any, any>[]> = 
    /**
     * Infer each element of the array
     */
    T[number] extends infer Elem 
    /**
     * Check if every element of the array extends Entity
     */
    ? Elem extends Entity<any, any> 
    /**
     * Check if keyof Elem['object'] extends `key` property
     * 1) if [key] property is one of object properties - return true
     * 2) if at least one element does not meet your requirements return false | true,
     * because some element are ok
     */
    ? keyof Elem['object'] extends Elem['key'] 
    ? true 
    : false 
    : false 
    : false;

// credits goes to https://stackoverflow.com/a/50375286
type UnionToIntersection<U> = (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends (
    k: infer I
) => void
    ? I
    : never;

// credits https://stackoverflow.com/users/125734/titian-cernicova-dragomir
type IsUnion<T> = [T] extends [UnionToIntersection<T>] ? false : true;

type Validator<T extends boolean> =
    /**
     * If IsValid returns false | true (boolean) it means Error
     * otherwise - ok
     */
    IsUnion<T> extends true ?
    ['Dear developer, please do smth right']
    /**
     * I'm using empty array here, because 
     * (...flag:[])=>any evaluates to function without arguments
     */
    : []

const foo = <
    Value extends Record<PropertyKey, string>,
    Key extends keyof Value,
    Data extends Entity<Value, Key>[],
>(a: [...Data], ...flag: [...Validator<IsValid<[...Data]>>]) => a

/**
 * Ok
 */
foo([{
    object: { name: 'John' }, key: 'name'
},
{
    object: { surname: 'John' }, key: 'surname'
}])

/**
 * Error
 */
foo([{
    object: { name: 'John' }, key: 'name'
},
{
    object: { surname: 'John' }, key: 'name'
}])
```

This solution consists of two parts:

**Part 1**

We need to infer ach element of the array with help of variadic tuple types - `Data` generic. [Here](https://dev.to/captainyossarian/typescript-type-inference-on-function-arguments-2n93), in my article, you can find an explanation how to do it.

**Part 2**

We need to check if every element meets your requirements: `Validator` and `IsValid` type utils. More about this technique you can find in my blog [here](https://catchts.com/validators) and [here](https://catchts.com/type-negation)